# Unreliable results using onbeforeunload

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, onbeforeunload

So I am using the onbeforeunload event to close any child windows (images) that have been opened from my parent window.  The code I am working with is old and the parent window does many post-backs for different operations so I am keeping track of the images server-side and adding the onbeforeunload attribute to the body when I need it.

When the window is to be closed the server-side code writes a script that simply calls a Javascript function with a string parameter.  The Javascript works fine, the problem is that it does not always get hit.

My server-side code looks like this:

```
private void CloseAllChildren()
{
     // some code to retrieve image window names...

     string script = "closeAllChildren('imagewindowname1,imagewindowname2,etc');";
     _body.Attributes.Add("onbeforeunload", script);
}
```

And the close method that is called when a close event is triggered:

```
private void Close()
{
     // A bunch of code...

     // close the window after all folders have been routed
     CloseAllChildren();
     this.Response.Write(FolderView.WindowClose);
}
```

I know nothing with computers is random, but my results do not seem to follow any sort of pattern.  Sometimes it hits the Javascript and works perfectly, sometimes it never hits the Javascript under the same test conditions.  I am assuming there is some kind of race condition but I am not sure how to detect or fix it.  Does anyone have any experience with this or a better way of doing it?  Like I said, the code is old and this was a small addition to functionality, so I do not want to change any of the current framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post what the event handler on the JavaScript side looks like ... oh wait; I guess you sort-of did post that.  But what about that "closeAllChildren" function?  What does that look like (the JavaScript version, not the server-side code that creates the call to it).

Comment: The Javascript just closes the windows it is told to based on the window's name, 'function closeAllChildren(names) {
    if (names != "") {
        var openedWindows = names.split(',');
        while (openedWindows.length > 0) {
            var winName = openedWindows.pop();
            var win = window.open(winName, winName);
            win.close();
        }
    }
}' This is not the problem though, if this method gets hit, it works without fail.  My issue lies in it not always getting hit.

Comment: Also, I am fairly new to posting on here, I don't really know how to add a code block in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the suggestions above and a few of my own ideas it seems the problem was that the javacript would end up executing the `window.top.close()` command before the onbeforeunload attribute was added (since it was being written dynamically), which is similar to what I expected.  I added a timeout of half a second by changing `window.top.close()` to `setTimeout(function() {window.top.close();}, 100)` and it seems to have fixed the "randomness" I was experiencing.

I appreciate the help, while I didn't end up using the other solutions they helped me find the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that your server-side close event is happening after the javascript onbeforeunload event has fired. Why do you conditionally add the javascript function call to your body tag? Why not just always add the handler in your javascript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = closeAllChildren('imagewindowname1,imagewindowname2,etc');
```

Then closeAllChildren will be called regardless of what the server is doing.

Comment: The parent page causes too many post-backs, so if I always handle it the windows will be closed when they shouldn't be.  I also need to add the parameters based on the names stored server-side, the parameters I typed in there are just an example.

Comment: @MGraffia [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx#Y0)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that helps.  The way I understand the onbeforeunload is that it is triggered just before the page unloads, which in the case of a postback would be just before I am able to catch anything with Page.IsPostBack.  Please correct me if I am wrong, but it doesn't look like checking whether or not there is a postback will solve this problem.

Comment: @MGraffia i think i see what you are trying to do. instead of attaching some javascript to the onbeforeunload event during your server side close event, what if you just inject the javascript call directly?

Comment: How can I do that, using a Response.Write?

Comment: @MGraffia Use [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx)